# Replacing whitespace in all column names in spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have spark dataframe with whitespaces in some of column names, which has to be replaced with underscore.

I know a single column can be renamed using `withColumnRenamed()` in sparkSQL, but to rename 'n' number of columns, this function has to chained 'n' times (to my knowledge).

To automate this, i have tried:

```
val old_names = df.columns()        // contains array of old column names

val new_names = old_names.map { x => 
   if(x.contains(" ") == true) 
      x.replaceAll("\\s","_") 
   else x 
}                    // array of new column names with removed whitespace.
```

Now, how to replace df's header with `new_names`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
  var newDf = df
  for(col <- df.columns){
    newDf = newDf.withColumnRenamed(col,col.replaceAll("\\s", "_"))
  }
```

You can encapsulate it in some method so it won't be too much pollution.

Comment: Can we use map method instead of using for loop?

Comment: In python use 'replace instead of 'replaceAll'

Answer (score 21):

As best practice, you should prefer expressions and immutability. 
You should use `val` and **not** `var` as much as possible.

Thus, it's preferable to use the `foldLeft` operator, in this case :

```scala
val newDf = df.columns
              .foldLeft(df)((curr, n) => curr.withColumnRenamed(n, n.replaceAll("\\s", "_")))
```

Comment: I've edited your answer adding some more value to the reason one should use operators instead of mutable variables.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Great pointing that the iterations should be dropped in favor of functional approach, using accumulators in recursive functions instead of saving values on heap at iterations.

Answer (score 14):

In Python, this can be done by the following code:

```py
# Importing sql types
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructType, StructField
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

# Building a simple dataframe:
schema = StructType([
             StructField("id name", StringType(), True),
             StructField("cities venezuela", StringType(), True)
         ])

column1 = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B']
column2 = ['Maracaibo', 'Valencia', 'Caracas', 'Barcelona', 'Barquisimeto', 'Merida']

# Dataframe:
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(list(zip(column1, column2)), schema=schema)
df.show()

exprs = [col(column).alias(column.replace(' ', '_')) for column in df.columns]
df.select(*exprs).show()
```

Answer (score 11):

You can do the exact same thing in python:

```
raw_data1 = raw_data
for col in raw_data.columns:
  raw_data1 = raw_data1.withColumnRenamed(col,col.replace(" ", "_"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Scala, here is another way achieving same  -

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

    val df_with_newColumns = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, 
StructType(df.schema.map(s => StructField(s.name.replaceAll(" ", ""), 
s.dataType, s.nullable))))
```

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the utility we are using.

```
 def columnsStandardise(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val dfcolumnsStandardise= df.toDF(df.columns map (_.toLowerCase().trim().replaceAll(" ","_")): _*)
    (dfcolumnsStandardise)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add also this solution

```
import re
for each in df.schema.names:
    df = df.withColumnRenamed(each, re.sub(r'\s+([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)\s*','',each.replace(' ', '')))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have being using the answer given by @kanielc to trim the leading and trailing spaces in the column headers and that works great when the number of columns are less. I had to load one csv file which had around 600 columns and execution of the code took a sufficient amount of time and was not meeting our expectations.

Earlier Code:

```
val finalSourceTable = intermediateSourceTable.columns
.foldLeft(intermediateSourceTable)((curr, n) => curr.withColumnRenamed(n, n.trim))
```

Changed Code:

```
val finalSourceTable = intermediateSourceTable
.toDF(intermediateSourceTable.columns map (_.trim()): _*)
```

The changed code worked like a charm and it was also fast compared to the earlier code.
Also we are maintaining the immutability by not using var variables.