# How to remove blank spaces from column names of Spark DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I remove blank spaces from column names of Spark DataFrame using Scala?

For example, I have column names "`Type`", "`Device ID`" and "`Office Address`". I would need to get "`Type`", "`DeviceID`" and "`OfficeAddress`"

Comment: I think this can help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018072/replacing-whitespace-in-all-column-names-in-spark-dataframe

Comment: @GalNaor: I checked the accepted solution. It does not work for me. I imported Column using "import org.apache.spark.sql.Column" and then I get the error "notebook:2: error: value replaceAll is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Column".

Comment: @Fluxy can you please provide the exact code you used to duplicate the solution?

Comment: Fluxy gave you different options in my answer please check also replaceall is string function not column function. pls review the code with result in my answer

Comment: @Fluxy Its a bit late I have seen this being marked as duplicate and redirected but none of those answers mentioned using `regexReplace` with `.withColumn` . That's how i would do. If its just blank spaces and white spaces I will use coalesce inside the `.withColumn` statement. What if I would like to replace other expressions and characters to be at specific indexed locations then this one comes handy. Just saying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `selectExpr` or `withColumn` approaches described below with full example:

while using select expr you have to use column names like this

```
"`Device ID` as DeviceId", "`Office Address` as OfficeAddress"
```

```
println("selectExpr approach")

    val basedf = Seq(
      (1, "100abcd", "8100 Memorial Ln Plano Texas")
      , (0, "100abcd1", "8100 Memorial Ln Plano Texas")
      , (0, "100abcd2", "8100 Memorial Ln Plano Texas")
      , (1, "100abcd2", "8100 Memorial Ln Plano Texas")
      , (1, "100abcd2", "8100 Memorial Ln Plano Texas")
    ).toDF("Type", "Device ID", "Office Address")
    basedf.show(false)
    basedf.selectExpr("Type as type", "`Device ID` as DeviceId", "`Office Address` as OfficeAddress").show(false)
    // second exaample
    println("with column approach")
   val df1 =  basedf
      .withColumn("DeviceID", $"Device Id")
      .withColumn("OfficeAddress", $"Office Address")
      .drop("Device Id", "Office Address")
    df1.show(false)
```

Result :

```
selectExpr approach
+----+---------+----------------------------+
|Type|Device ID|Office Address              |
+----+---------+----------------------------+
|1   |100abcd  |8100 Memorial Ln Plano Texas|
|0   |100abcd1 |8100 Memorial Ln Plano Texas|
|0   |100abcd2 |8100 Memorial Ln Plano Texas|
|1   |100abcd2 |8100 Memorial Ln Plano Texas|
|1   |100abcd2 |8100 Memorial Ln Plano Texas|
+----+---------+----------------------------+

+----+--------+----------------------------+
|type|DeviceId|OfficeAddress               |
+----+--------+----------------------------+
|1   |100abcd |8100 Memorial Ln Plano Texas|
|0   |100abcd1|8100 Memorial Ln Plano Texas|
|0   |100abcd2|8100 Memorial Ln Plano Texas|
|1   |100abcd2|8100 Memorial Ln Plano Texas|
|1   |100abcd2|8100 Memorial Ln Plano Texas|
+----+--------+----------------------------+

with column approach
+----+--------+----------------------------+
|Type|DeviceID|OfficeAddress               |
+----+--------+----------------------------+
|1   |100abcd |8100 Memorial Ln Plano Texas|
|0   |100abcd1|8100 Memorial Ln Plano Texas|
|0   |100abcd2|8100 Memorial Ln Plano Texas|
|1   |100abcd2|8100 Memorial Ln Plano Texas|
|1   |100abcd2|8100 Memorial Ln Plano Texas|
+----+--------+----------------------------+
```

***Generic way of doing irrespective of what column names has white space is like below...***

```
println("Generic column rename approach for n number of Columns")
    basedf.printSchema()
    var newDf: DataFrame =  basedf
    newDf.columns.foreach { col =>
      println(col + " after column replace " + col.replaceAll(" ", ""))
      newDf = newDf.withColumnRenamed(col, col.replaceAll(" ", "")
      )
    }
    newDf.printSchema()
    newDf.show(false)
```

Result :

```
Generic column rename approach for ***n*** number of Columns
root
 |-- Type: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- Device ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Office Address: string (nullable = true)

Type after column replace Type
Device ID after column replace DeviceID
Office Address after column replace OfficeAddress
root
 |-- Type: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- DeviceID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- OfficeAddress: string (nullable = true)

+----+--------+----------------------------+
|Type|DeviceID|OfficeAddress               |
+----+--------+----------------------------+
|1   |100abcd |8100 Memorial Ln Plano Texas|
|0   |100abcd1|8100 Memorial Ln Plano Texas|
|0   |100abcd2|8100 Memorial Ln Plano Texas|
|1   |100abcd2|8100 Memorial Ln Plano Texas|
|1   |100abcd2|8100 Memorial Ln Plano Texas|
+----+--------+----------------------------+
```

> ***Conclusion*** :
>
> Out of all these 3 approaches I will prefer generic approach since if
>   you have large number of columns it can efficiently handle the rename
>   with out hiccups